# Are there any Bitcoin Payment solutions for Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bitcoin

Working in Ruby (and perhaps Rails). Are there any ways of accepting and managing payments in Bitcoin for Ruby or Rails?

Answer (score 6):

Have you looked at Github: https://github.com/lian/bitcoin-ruby

There are a few other gems up there related to bitcoin written in Ruby.

See query: https://github.com/search?q=bitcoin+ruby&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults

Comment: This looks good, but it seems to be just for using the Bitcoin protocol. I am looking for more of a shopping cart solution...

Answer (score 4):

There is a Ruby example code here https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_%28JSON-RPC%29#Ruby  
Also check this gem in Github https://github.com/davout/bitcoin-central

Comment: I saw that gem but it hasn't been updated in a year...

Comment: @BSeven sorry I did not notice that, did you try the gem?

Comment: No, I am looking for a more complete solution that supports a monthly subscription payment via Bitcoin.

Answer (score 2):

I developped http://microbitcoin.fr in RoR starting from Dave Thomas awesome tutorial "Agile Web Development in Rails".
It shows a bitcoin cart/checkout (allowing other payment methods) with email notification, qrcode pdf invoice download etc.. A new bitcoin address is generated for each transaction.
The app comes with full admin capability to create and update a product catalog.
I integrated a deterministic bitcoin wallet so that the shop keeper can use a regular electrum wallet to receive payments while the web server is not holding any private key. The app knows only the master public key of the wallet: this is the safest option.
Feedback is welcome and I'd be happy to share the code.

Comment: I don't it's late in the game. Bitcoin has barely gotten started!

Comment: The code of the Ruby weshop is now available on [GitHub](https://github.com/pierrenoizat/webshop)

Answer (score 2):

[bitcoin_payable](https://github.com/Sailias/bitcoin_payable)

A gem I've created that can be included in a rails app.

It creates payments with unique addresses from a BIP32 Deterministic seed.  These payments use different currencies to get exchanges rates from currency -> BTC.

A rake task is used to update payments every 30 mins with the BTC 24 hour weighted average while another uses [helloblock.io](https://helloblock.io/) to check for payments.

It is not a shopping cart solution, but a bitcoin payment generator / processor gem that doesn't require indexing the blockchain or storing private keys on your server.

Answer (score 1):

I developed a RoR site that takes payment in Bitcoin for shared hosting.

The source is here: https://github.com/georgeu2000/coinhost